# How can I root the Samsung Galaxy Note 3 SM-N900V?

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, root-access, samsung-galaxy-note-3

I recently updated my phone to Android 5.0. I have been searching for a way to root this device for days and have tried every tool and technique out there including Cf-Auto-Root, Kingo Root, and Towelroot without success.

People say that Towelroot worked on Android versions prior to the latest updated version 5.0. They say that the bootloader is locked and no tool available currently works. Is there any way to get this device rooted or is it impossible to root it?

Comment: Man, I've been trying to root my SM-900V allllll day now. They even made it impossible to downgrade back to 4.4.2 (where it is possible to root). It must be strictly a Verizon thing because I've found several ways to successfully root different models of the device. Looks like we're out of luck for now. :/

Comment: It's as simple downloading the ArabicTool and these steps: How to us:
1. Enable usb debugging.
2. Accepte notification in your phone to Allow USB debugging authorization.
3. click Read Phone Info
4. click root and wait to comliting root.
5. Install SuperUser form google play.

Comment: @DeliriousSyntax Did you actually try the method you mentioned with SM-N900V 5.0? Because I highly doubt it's that simple.

Comment: @chaosifier Why would you doubt it to be that easy? It's called a one click root method for a reason. One Click Root is actually one of the most popular method to rooting because it is literally that simple.

Comment: @EcstaticSnow, can you provide a link to the tool that you're talking about?

Comment: @chaosifier I actually did post the link(and 2 other links for other methods I found), but one of the mods deleted that comment, so I don't know if I should/could.

Comment: @EcstaticSnow, if you really think your solution works, then dafaq is this : http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/141101/how-to-root-galaxy-note-3-sm-n900v-running-5-0-lollipop

Comment: @chaosifier Someone pointed me to those links after I posted the Question... And yes it works

Comment: A bootloader unlock also just came out for this device 3 days ago. Will try it soon

Comment: @EcstaticSnow, please do. And make sure you share your solution at xda as well and also make a video tutorial if possible. There are people who would kill to get their phones rooted.

Comment: @chaosifier I found it on XDA http://forum.xda-developers.com/verizon-galaxy-note-3/general/official-note-3-verizon-bootloader-t3359370

Comment: @EcstaticSnow, Thanks man!! You were right about the Arabic Tool, it did the trick! I finally got my phone rooted! See my answer for the rooting process.

Comment: @chaosifier Your welcome mate I did post the links to it a while ago. Sorry you couldn't have seen them before they were removed. Glad it helped you though. And just wondering what OS were you using on the PC you used to root?

Comment: @EcstaticSnow, it was Windows 10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guys at XDA again did the magic and finally found a way to root this infamous SM-N900V running lollipop 5.0. Here's the entire process in detail:

Follow the steps below to root your device:

- Install the samsung mobile USB driver. Plug in your note 3 to a PC, a CD drive pops up for few seconds, open it, you'll find the driver for your device there.
- Now enable developer mode and USB debugging on your device.
- Download and open the [ArabicToolApp](http://forum.xda-developers.com/verizon-galaxy-note-3/general/official-note-3-verizon-bootloader-t3359370).
- Inside the tool, Select the baseband version of your device, you can find this information under ( Settings > About phone > Baseband version ) of your android device. Note the last 3 characters and select the Version in the Arabic Tool accordingly.
- Click on Read Phone Info. Now, note the log messages in the Arabic Tool, you should only procced if no warnings are given there.
- No press ROOT button.

The rooting process should not take more than 6 minutes. If it does, cancel the Arabic Tool and do the following and try again.
- Make sure you've restarted your computer after installing the USB drivers.
- Use USB 2.0 cable and port.

If during the process, your device gets stuck on the bootscreen, do the following:
- Turn off your device, Press (Home + Volume Up + Power) buttons to get into the recovery mode, reset the device from the menu and also clear the cache partition. Now, try restarting your device. If the bootloop still persists, follow the next step.

- If the above step didn't fix the problem, you will have to reflash your firmware. To do this, [download Odin](https://www.google.com.np/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiKn7Ciq6TMAhULkI4KHVxdA-8QFggaMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fodindownload.com%2F&usg=AFQjCNGiNM9s-jD9BfUGTxuSFUeL5hLzfQ&sig2=0oVh11FJMBwH9Do1GjLaVQ&bvm=bv.119745492,d.c2E) and [SM-N900v OF1 firmware](http://www.sammobile.com/firmwares/confirm/54179/N900VVRUEOF1_N900VVZWEOF1_VZW/) from the link provided below.
- Start Odin
- Reboot phone in Download Mode by pressing (Home + Volume Down + Power) buttons.
- Connect phone and wait for the blue sign in Odin.
- Add the downloaded firmware file to AP/PDA
- Click the start button and wait for it to show the "Pass" sign. This can take upto 10 minutes.

Once your device starts running normally, make sure you follow the rooting steps given above correctly and try again.

To confirm that your device is rooted, you can press the device info button in the Arabic Tool once again to see the root status or, you could also install RootChecker app from the playstore and see it there.

Once you've confirmed that your device is rooted, install SuperSu and follow the instructions in it to install required binaries.

Guys at XDA recently also found a way to unlock the bootloader of this device. Follow the XDA thread below for more information.
[Note 3 Verizon Bootloader Unlock](http://forum.xda-developers.com/verizon-galaxy-note-3/general/official-note-3-verizon-bootloader-t3359370)

Comment: If it worked ( which it seems to) please mark it as an answer? It helps tie up loose ends.

Comment: I can't find ArabicToolApp, only unlock_n3